# How to design a keyboard circuit that can use a passive USB-to-PS/2 adapter?

Tags: usb, keyboard

I'm designing a small device that will act as a USB HID keyboard, but it must also work with PS/2 hosts. I would *really* want to be able to use it with one of these nifty passive USB-to-PS/2 adapters that used to come with every USB keyboard (not sure if they still do, haven't bought a keyboard in many years!). Problem is, *how can I detect if to use USB or PS/2 in my circuit?*

[image: Passive USB to PS/2 adapter]

### Electrical connection

Since I'm using a [PIC16F1454](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001639B.pdf) which has a built-in 3.3V LDO, trancievers, and everything for USB my plan was to connect it like this:

[image: Simple electrical connection]

I need to connect RA4/5 because D+ and D- can only be used as inputs if they are not used for USB communication. RA4 and RA5 would normally be tri-stated, thus not conflict with the USB, and if the PS/2 mode is enabled, D+ and D- would be disabled in a similar fashion.

I don't foresee any major problems because D+/D- are 3.3V and PS/2 is 5V. Because [PS/2 is using an open-collector](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2protocol/) configuration, any mistake that causes 5V to go out on the USB D+/D- will have a very high impedance, and should not break anything.

### Logical

Now, here's the main problem. I'm not sure how I would perform my initialization procedure to detect PS/2 or USB at startup.

One problem is that, from what I understand, there is not a single standard mapping between the USB D+/D- and the PS/2 Clock/Data pins in these passive adapters. Either D+ is connected to Clock and D- to Data, or vice versa. This also leads to the first real question: **Is there a standard pin mapping?** If not an official standard, perhaps a de facto standard? If there is not, I don't think there will be a problem detecting this in software.

The second question is, well, how do I actually detect if the host is talking to me using USB or PS/2? Preferably in a reliable way. Since every keyboard i have here works with one of those adapters without exception, it can't be that hard. Does the USB standard perhaps discuss this? Few adapters actually carry the USB logo, so I don't think this is something that the USB standard would encourage.

Comment: You could assume USB on power-up, but if no USB activity happens within some period of time then switch to PS/2.

Comment: You have to worry about the digital input buffers of RA4 and RA5, "tristating" only deals with the output buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than follow the above comment success will more likely detect if the two pins are pulled up to 5V. *(Make sure you use an MCU that has 5V compatible GPIO pins)*. PS/2 does run as open collector but in the immediate interval after the power supply is up to valid level the interface will be still inactive and both of the PS/2 lines will be undriven and high at 5V. This may require you to add some extra circuitry to detect this as opposed to some lower USB signal levels.

What is the incentive to support PS/2 in this day and age?

**Added Information**

The data sheet for your PIC16F1454 indicates that the connection of the PS/2 signal lines into the USB D+ and D- may not be advisable. The **Absolute Maximum Ratings** section has this to say about the D+ and D- pins:

[image]
[image]

With this information in hand it is not recommended to subject the D+ and D- pins to over 3.3V + 0.5V = 3.8V and certainly NEVER over 4.6V.

Comment: Keep in mind that PS/2 can often have lower latency than USB. For that reason, it's sometimes used in "pro" gaming products. Also, there are always reasons to keep back-compatibility and to not break user expectations.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - Your comment makes sense. I fully anticipate that in a few more years PS/2 may very well disappear from new desktop products.

Comment: I do too. On the other hand, there's still a market for AT to PS/2 adapters as well, so I expect that users will expect the support for PS/2 to be available for a while longer.

Comment: Thank you. My MCU only has 5V GPIO, its USB pins are a special case, but it's a good comment for someone else who's trying this! My particular incentive is to support old hardware. In fact, my "client" (a friend) does not even care about USB.

Comment: @pipe - See added comment in my answer regarding pin voltages.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! This certainly warrants further investigation, because it is not clear if those limits are in place when the physical pins are used for other functions. They can for example be reconfigured as pins for in-circuit programming, and the external programmer will not know about the 3.3 volt limit.

Comment: I asked Microchip's engineering support about the maximum voltage. They were not sure, so they had to pass it on to the engineers, but now I received The pins RA0 and RA1, and I'm quoting their response: "The pins in questions have an absolute voltage tolerance of 5.5V. (This includes general I/O functions.) "